# Call HttpResponseMessage in C# but it exits with no error with REST API

Tags: c#, rest, powerbi

I am working through the below code in C# tryin to call a REST API.  This code works when I have it in it's own individual C# application.  However, when I try to combine it into another app where I want to call it from so I can clone reports dynamically the HttpResponseMessage just exits with no response, no error or anything.

So basically I debug, I step line by line through.  When it gets to HttpResponseMessage it exits the ReportClone.Main() class and starts DatasetManager.ConnectToSQLServer() class.  With no error messages that i can see.

Here is the code that is calling the report clone REST API.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;

namespace PowerBI_Development {

  class Program {

    static void Main() {


            ReportClone.Main();

            DatasetManager.ConnectToSQLServer();


        }


  }
}
```

Which then calls this file:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace PowerBI_Development 
{
    internal class ReportClone
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public static async Task Main()

        {

            try
            {
                var reportName = "REPORT_NAME";
                var reportID = "REPORT_ID";
                var targetModelID = "TARGET_MODEL_ID";
                var targetWorkspaceID = "TARGET_WORKSPACE_ID";
                var bearer = "BEARER TOKEN";

                var url = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportID}/Clone";
                var data = "{\r\n  \"name\": \"" + reportName + "\",\r\n  \"targetModelId\": \"" + targetModelID + "\",\r\n  \"targetWorkspaceId\": \"" + targetWorkspaceID + "\"\r\n}";
               

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);

                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Error copying reports: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get this to work in a separate file but would like to combine it so I can loop through the rest api while I am looping through creating datasets.  I want to create a dataset and a report together.

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do or experiencing. Is it by design that you do not await the `ReportClone.Main();`? That can cause race contitions as I currently see it, which may lead to missing `Console` results

Comment: @XWIKO I'm new to C# so I'm not the best at this.  Sorry for the confusion.  My ultimate goal is to call the REST API so clone a power bi report.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok. Make the `static void Main` an `static async Task Main`. Await the `ReportClone.Main();`. And dont swallow the exception in the Try Catch block (`throw ex;`). I bet you will see some results.

Comment: Thank you @XWIKO!!!  Made those changes and it worked!!!  I don't see how I can mark your comment as an answer but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from @XWIKO in the comments.  They mentioned to do the following:

> Ok. Make the static void Main an static async Task Main. Await the ReportClone.Main();. And dont swallow the exception in the Try Catch block (throw ex;). I bet you will see some results. –
> XWIKO
> Oct 5 at 20:26

Which I took and created this code that worked:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;


namespace PowerBI_Development 
{

    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main()
        {

            
            DatasetManager.GetCompanyCategoryFormID();


            await ReportClone.callReportCloneRestAPI();

            



        }


    }
}
```